# C function returns a value but caller assigns another value

Tags: c, return-value

I have a C function named `from_binary_to_decimal`, which is called by another function `x_caching`. The problem is that `from_binary_to_decimal` returns for example 2.25 (a float) but `x_caching` (that has a line wrote to store the return value) modifies the previous value returned by the first function.

I put images of the code (in the order under which they are executed):

```
float** cache_provider(struct INPUT_DATA* d, char** arrszChromosomes)
{
    static float** arrfCache = NULL;
    int i;
    if (d == NULL && arrszChromosomes == NULL) return arrfCache;

    if (arrfCache == NULL)
    {
        arrfCache = (float**)malloc(d->m_iPopulationSize * sizeof(float*));
        for (i = 0; i < d->m_iPopulationSize; ++i)
        arrfCache[i] = (float*)malloc(2 * sizeof(float));
    }

    x_caching(d, arrszChromosomes, &arrfCache);

    return arrfCache;
```

}

```
void x_caching(struct INPUT_DATA *d,
               char **arrszChromosomes,
               float **arrfCache)
{  
    int i;
    float fTemp = 0.0f;

    for (i = 0; i < d->m_iPopulationSize; ++i) {
        arrfCache[i][0] = get_cache_key(arrszChromosomes[i]);
        fTemp = from_binary_to_decimal(d, arrszChromosomes[i], 0);
        arrfCache[i][1] = fTemp;
    }
}

float from_binary_to_decimal(struct INPUT_DATA *d,
                             char *szChromosome,
                             int iCacheQuery)
{  
    float fRetVal = 0.0;
    float fFinal = 0.0f;
    float *fCacheVal = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    if (iCacheQuery
        && (fCacheVal = get_x_value_from_cache(szChromosome)) != NULL)
        return *fCacheVal;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(szChromosome); ++i)
        fRetVal +=
            (szChromosome[i] == '1' ? 1 : 0) *
            powf(2, d->m_iBitsPChromosome - (i + 1));

    fFinal = d->m_arrcDomainInterval[0] + (fRetVal * d->m_fDelta);
    return fFinal;
}
```

`fTemp` was supposed to store a number like 2.51 instead it is storing a value like 8133608.

Comment: Post the code here as text, No one will bother following your link

Comment: I updated my question if it isn't formatted properly it is because I'm about to run out of rep. Help please. Thanks.

Comment: at what point do you examine the value of `fTemp`? did you use a debugger?

Comment: Yes, I used a debugger. I examined its value right after it returned from the function from_binary_to_decimal (inside it at the return sentence the value was correct). The assignment to fTemp fails, it assigns a number never matches the one returned.

Answer (score 3):

For starters the number of float arrays you're allocating, and your array indexes used to access them, are different:

```
arrfCache = (float**)malloc(d->m_iMaxGenerations * sizeof(float*));
for (i = 0; i < d->m_iPopulationSize; ++i)
    arrfCache[i] = (float*)malloc(2 * sizeof(float));
```

You've allocated `d->m_iMaxGenerations` float arrays, but you're iterating through `d->m_iPopulationSize` of them.

Same for the `for` loop where you have `fTemp`:

```
for (i = 0; i < d->m_iPopulationSize; ++i)
```

You're accessing `arrfCache` for `d->m_iPopulationSize` arrays, when you've only allocated `d->m_iMaxGenerations`.  If `d->m_iMaxGenerations` is smaller, this could lead to memory corruption and weird values such as you've seen.

Answer (score 3):

You never set `arrfCache` to non-null value. Futhermore, the x_caching should have declaration of the form:

```
void x_caching (struct INPUT_DATA* d, char** arrszChromosomes, float*** arrfCache)
```

As you want arrfCache to be output parameter.

```
x_caching(d, arrszChromosomes, &arrfTempCache);
...
*arrfCache = malloc(....)
....
(*arrfCache)[i][0] = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the malloc errors up wilsonmichaelpatrick, I corrected them but the error remains. Valeri Atamaniouk, could you explain to me why I would need that type of declaration for arrfCache? I just need a two-dimensional array for which a declaration like float** will do just fine. I almost forgot there's an assignment of type arrfTempCache = NULL in cache_provider, this is passed as a reference to the other function.

Comment: @JorgeCespedes You are trying to use a parameter, which actually returns value. As your type is `float**`, you need to add a pointer to it to let your function change variable value, so the parameter becomes `float ***`. Yes, it is a bit confusing, but this is how you can modify value of the caller. Respectfully, all references to the value shall be using `*` operator. You can keep the `float**` type as input, only if you add it also to return type, and your code will look like: `arrfTempCache = x_caching(d, arrszChroms, arrfTempCache`. Respectfully, the function needs to return the right val.

Comment: @ValeruAtamaniouk I understand now, I'll make this modification and see if it works now. Thanks

Comment: It isn't working yet, I've made all of the modifications but no luck. The first assignment made to fTemp fails I don't know why from_binary_to_decimal returns a valid number and this assignment fails, even before storing it in the array

Comment: I'm still struggling against this error, any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: please update the question with what you have now. preferably function by function with description what you expect from it.

Comment: I was working on another project and I returned to this a few hours ago.. Is it possible that the compiler didn't detect a function redefinition? What I mean is that from_binary_to_decimal was defined below x_caching and this function is calling from_binary_to_decimal before it exists, It is just weird to me considering that I didn't even specify from_binary_to_decimal prototype (which actually solved the problem at last!). I would expect the compiler to complain about a redefinition since it couldn't even have found a prototype for this function.

Comment: @JorgeCespedes Interesting effect. Yes, it can be, as if the prototype is missing, the compiler assumes `int` return value. So what happens is that function returns `float` but it it treated as `int` and converted to `float`. Nice case.